# How are underground fuel pipes monitored for leakage?

Tags: airport

This question is about environmental risk associated with high pressure lines underground at airports.

My understanding is that there is a matrix of high pressure fuel lines underground to each gate, while the source of the fuel are the main tanks. What environmental (and operational) safeguards are in-place to detect leaks to the environment?

Comment: One _could_ make the assumption that, since this was asked on [Aviation.se] that the intent is to ask about built-in fueling systems at airports, and I'd think that would be on topic. However, some clarification from the OP would go a long way toward helping with that understanding.

Comment: Related (not answering this question): [How do large airport refueling systems work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38106/3201)

Comment: What goes in must come out, if something is going in while nothing comes out then you have a leak.

Comment: Thank you.  The gist is environmental risk associated with high pressure lines underground.  Understanding is that there is a matrix of high pressure fuel lines underground to each gate, source of fuel is main tanks.  What environmental (and operational) safeguards are in-place to detect leaks to the environment?  Thanks again--

Comment: I have edited the question for you, next time please use the edit button instead of the comments, this will help get your question reviewed for reopening

Comment: I used to perform aerial patrol of buried petroleum product pipelines, including certain interstate transport lines. However, this question seems to be asking about the non-interstate, local transportation lines within the airport facility. I am not sure that subject is on-topic here.

Comment: @RalphJ It's aviation fuel coming out of those pipes.

Comment: @Koyovis Yes, but that still doesn't make the question ***about aviation***, any more than a question about how dress shirts are sewn suddenly decomes on topic when we specify that the question is about how ***pilots'*** dress shirts are sewn. That question is about sewing, not flying, and this question is about the design & safeguards in fuel systems, not flying. That planes, rather than ships or racecars or whoever else needs complex underground fuel distribution, will burn the fuel doesn't change the question enough to make it on topic here. IMHO.

Comment: @RalphJ The logistics of what happens at an airport, with all the support activities such as guiding into the gate, unloading, fuelling etc are aviation related, just as loading trucks is trucking related. If pilot dress shirts had specific distinctive requirements because of their work environment, that would make the question aviation related. Is a discussion about the aluminium used in aircraft aviation related or for a metallurgic forum? There is a large gray area where topics of interest may be found, IMHO the broader the better.